# AForge.NET Image Color Manipulation

Tags: image, filter, bitmap, aforge

I discovered AForge a few days ago with a goal in mind. I wanted to be able to manipulate an image's colors. However, after trying several different methods I have not been able to find a resolution.
I looked thoroughly through the documentation they give, but it hasn't been any help to me. The specific part of the documentation I have been using is:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/3aaa490f-8dbe-f179-f64b-eedd0b9d34ac.htm

The example they give:

```
// create filter
YCbCrLinear filter = new YCbCrLinear( );
// configure the filter
filter.InCb = new Range( -0.276f, 0.163f );
filter.InCr = new Range( -0.202f, 0.500f );
// apply the filter
filter.ApplyInPlace( image );
```

I replicated it for a button click event, but the 'image' portion of it wasn't specified. I converted the image inside of my picturebox to a bitmap, then referenced it in the last line thinking that it would work. But it had no affect at all.
My code is the following:

```
private void ColManButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
YCbCrLinear filter = new YCbCrLinear();
filter.InCb = new Range(-0.276f, 0.163f);
filter.InCr = new Range(-0.202f, 0.500f);
filter.ApplyInPlace(newimage);
}
```

My question essentially is, to anyone familiar or willing to help with this framework, how do I take my image and manipulate its color using AForge's YCbCrLinear Class under my button's click event?

Answer (score 2):

Remember to set the picture box image after you have applied the filtering.

```
private void ColManButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    YCbCrLinear filter = new YCbCrLinear();
    filter.InCb = new Range(-0.276f, 0.163f);
    filter.InCr = new Range(-0.202f, 0.500f);
    filter.ApplyInPlace(newimage);

    pictureBox1.Image = newimage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

at the aforge website you can download the source code of a sample filter application, did you try it ?